# Prevent 'save design changes' for an open form when closing Access

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2010

I have a split form as my main interface in an Access 2010 application.  As normal, users are able to resize the datasheet portion, reorder columns, etc.

However, I don't want them to save such changes when leaving the form.  Each time the form is opened the default format should be loaded.

I've taken care of all but one closing method.  To avoid them closing using the default close button I've set Border Style = None.  Instead I have a Close Form button that uses `DoCmd.CLOSE acForm, "Main_form", acSaveNo`

But if the user clicks the close button for the Access application, it pops the 'Do you want to save changes to the design of form` dialog like always.

I looked into disabling the application's Close button, but messing with Windows API is beyond my skill (and there should be a way to accomplish this without going to extreme measures).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found a way to do this.  A combination of database options, form format options, and vba can do it.

1. Go to the 'Current Database' options screen in the main Access
   options and uncheck 'Enable design changes in Datasheet view'.  This will prevent *all* datasheet view design changes in the database, so you will have to go into design mode for any table changes.  Users can still reorder and resize columns within a form, but Access no longer considers that a valid design change and will not prompt to save it no matter how you close the form
2. Set the form format property 'Save Splitter Bar Position' = No.  The form will now clear any change to the bar location when the form is closed.  Access got really weird on me about this setting, however.  Once I had *ever* set the option to no, I could no longer use design view or layout view to set a new default bar position; it always reverted to the location where it was when I first tried this setting.  Even resetting the option to Yes, saving the design change, and fully exiting the database did not fix this.
3. So I added an On Load event to reset the split form size when the form opens: `Me.SplitFormSize = 9000`.  The numbers involved are surprisingly high; in the form properties list this is set in inches.  Mine was 6.5", which apparently translates to 9000.

With these three changes (along with the steps I detailed in the question) Access no longer prompts to save design changes when the form is closed, even if the user is closing the Access application entirely.  The form also snaps the split form bar back to where it should be on load.

Comment: Sizes in VBA are given in Twips. "Twip" is a unit of measurement equal to 1/20th of a printers point. There are 1440 twips to an inch, 567 twips to a centimeter. [Source](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/76388)

Comment: @Andre that's cool to know. Do you know of a use case where a difference of, say, 5 twips would do anything? useful?

Comment: Hardly, no. :) I use the metric system, so I always have a constant `Const TPC = 567` (twips per centimeter) in my code, and do all calculations with that, e.g. `Me.someControl.Top = 0.5 * TPC`.

Comment: You can also turn off 'Enable design changes in Datasheet view' in VBA with `CurrentDb.Properties("AllowDatasheetSchema") = False` and there is more info described [here](https://www.fmsinc.com/microsoftaccess/Options/TableDesignChange/AllowDatasheetSchema.asp).

Answer (score 1):

Since the API is beyond my skill too, here is a left-field workaround.

Duplicate `Main_Form` and rename it "Main_Form_Template". Create an Autoexec module or edit an existing one and add:

```
DoCmd.DeleteObject acForm, "Main_Form"
DoCmd.CopyObject , "Main_Form", acForm, "Main_Form_Template"
```

That should reinstate the standard template for the user each time they open the database even if they were to save the form when closing Access.

Comment: I don't think this will work well for me; if another user in in the database using the form when the autoexec deletes the form that would be trouble.

Comment: @Christopher D.  I like that.  Will have to use that sometime.  Rominus, are you working off a shared copy of database?

Comment: I know you said runtimes are out, what about a split db? Distributing local front-end accdbs to users would allow you to delete the object without fear of someone else having the object open. I agree that this will not work on a shared file though.

Comment: Or you could test to see if the form is open in the Autoexec and cancel if it is. Eventually someone will be the first to open that db and then the template would be reinstated. It may let changes float around for a bit, but eventually it would revert without manual design changes.

Comment: @ChristopherD. This is an Access front end hooked up to SQL Server, so I had discarded the idea of using Access's split database functions.  Now that you mention it though, I could give everyone a copy of the app connected to the SQL Server for the same result.

Comment: @geeFlo yep, shared

Comment: Even if you don't end up using this solution, I do recommend distributing local front-ends instead of sharing the same front end file with multiple users. I don't think there are huge downsides to the share, but it makes development, deployment, and version control a bit more straight-forward if each user has their own local copy. Glad you were able to get it working!

Answer (score 0):

Turn your close button off on the form.

On the form's property sheet, format tab, about 2/3 of way down.  Set Close Button = No

This forces the user to close it via the button you created.

Comment: Oh okay.  I see it now.  Hmmm, if users are prone to changing forms, maybe it's time to start distributing MDE/ACCDE versions of your database.

Comment: Yeah, I'd love to do it that way, but company IT is not a fan of executable runtimes

Comment: Perhaps have a hidden form that triggers the other form to close?  i.e. Use FormX's "OnClose" property to perform the closure with an acSaveNo parameter.

Comment: But then this would need to trigger FormX to close first, in order to close all others.  (Sorry, just brainstorming here)

Comment: Got it!  I've posted my answer if you're interested.